# App sandbox: how to allow XPC service to read file that user opened in parent app?

Tags: cocoa, sandbox, appstore-sandbox, xpc

I have a simple Cocoa image preview app. The user selects a file using an `NSOpenPanel` and the app generates a preview image using the Quick Look API.

I'd like to move the preview generation into a separate XPC service. Without app sandboxing everything works fine, but after enabling app sandboxing for the parent app and the XPC service, *the XPC service is denied read access to the user selected file*.

The parent app is allowed to read the file (because it was selected through an NSOpenPanel).

How do I transfer the "file read" permissions for the user-selected file from the parent app to the XPC process so that the XPC process can read the file to generate the preview?

My XPC service requests file-read access via its entitlements and I added the following key to the XPC Service Info.plist, but that did not help:

```
JoinExistingSession = YES
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I think Apple recommends passing an `NSFileHandle` to the XPC process in this case. That way, the XPC process can access the file's contents but does not need to know the file's URL.

Edit: [This thread in the Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/142513?start=0&tstart=0) is helpful. The recommendation is to create a normal (not security-scoped) bookmark for the URL of the file. This bookmark can then be passed to the XPC process and accessed by it.

Comment: Thanks! Solution was to create a security scoped bookmark, create an NSURL out of that, then take the url and create a **normal** bookmark to send to the XPC service.

Comment: I can also confirm this worked: request for the file URL in main process, store security scoped bookmark data for it there, then send non-scoped bookmark data to XPC process and create a file URL there. Importantly also directory file URLs worked such that you get access to subdirectories and files under the directory for whom bookmark data was sent.

Comment: This solution that worked up until now seems to have now been broken by OSX 10.11.12, at least for executing programs.

Comment: @Ole Begemann, the Apple Dev Forum link is broken now I think :(