# How do you create an NSURL from a file descriptor?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, core-foundation, xpc

This question is really about transferring file permissions from a parent macOS application that is not sandboxed, to a child XPC service that is sandboxed.

This question, [App sandbox: how to allow XPC service to read file that user opened in parent app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361043), is almost identical in purpose, but differs in implementation. (An accepted answer on that question involves sending a security-scoped bookmark across, which works, but is really slow.)

The lower-level implementation that Apple seems to recommend is to send a file descriptor over to the XPC service. Apple's [Secure Coding Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html) talks about this very issue under "Inheriting File Descriptors".

Using the C-based XPC framework, I can successfully send a file descriptor from the main application to the XPC service and read data using that file descriptor:

**In the main app:**

```
NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"..."];
xpc_dictionary_set_fd(dict, "fd", handle.fileDescriptor);
```

**In the XPC service:**

```
 int fd = xpc_dictionary_dup_fd(dict, "fd");
 NSFileHandle *handle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fd 
                                                   closeOnDealloc:YES];

 NSData *data = [handle readDataOfLength:1000];
 NSLog(@"Read data of length: %@", @(data.length));
```

The XPC service is able to read that data. However, any attempts to now create an NSURL using a file path (`NSString`) that points to the same file will fail. This is problematic because the APIs that I want to use in the XPC service all require an `NSURL`.

I can't see anyway to create an `NSURL` from a file descriptor nor convert a file descriptor into an `NSURL`, but perhaps I've overlooked something.

Is there a way to create an NSURL from a file descriptor, or have a newly created NSURL inherit the read-only permissions of the file descriptor?

Alternatively, is there another way to transfer file permissions from a parent process to a child XPC process that doesn't involve having to create an security scoped bookmark, archiving it and then unarchiving it on the other end?

*macOS 10.12/10.13*

**Edit 1**

Apple's [SandboxedFetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SandboxedFetch/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code uses the file descriptor technique perfectly, but the functions it uses in the XPC service are able to take file descriptors. Namely, it just uses `read()`, `fdopen()` and `curl`.

Comment: What are the APIs that you want to use in the service that take URLs? Perhaps there are alternatives that can work with a file descriptor.

Comment: Just about every API :) Specifically, APIs for reading images with Image IO and Core Image, reading and decoding media using AVFoundation and using QuickLook to generate thumbnail previews of files. I can get the NSFileHandle across and read using it, but I can't create a new NSURL that is readable. (I tried passing over a file descriptor for the parent directory, but that didn't seem to work either, or I did it wrong.)  I assumed that App Sandbox would see I have an open file descriptor and allow subsequent file descriptors via NSURL to the same file but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: You could read in data using the file handle, and create your image source/CIImage/whatever using that data, maybe.

Comment: Also, you could probably send the path/URL string over the XPC connection as well.

Comment: Even with the path, I don't appear able to create a new NSURL that is readable. In the C interface for XPC, there's no way to send an NSURL, though I'd be surprised if that mattered since I *assume* the Objective-C interface is built on the C interface. Reading in image data and using a data provider could work for images, but that would involve reading in all the data when you might only need a little bit. (Like extracting the JPEG thumbnail from a RAW file.) For generating video thumbnails, reading all the data isn't really practical.